# Find minimum distance between points of two lists in Python

Tags: python, optimization

I have two lists of coordinates:

```
s1 = [(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)]
s2 = [(3,2), (1,9)]
```

I want to calculate the minimum distance of each point in s1 to any point in s2. e.g. the results should be as follows.

```
result = [3.60, 3.16, 2.82, 2.23]
```

**Question:** What is the most optimized way in terms of execution time, to achieve this result?

So far I've tried this but the execution time is not promising:

```
import math
def nearestDistance(boundary, p):
    minDistList = map(lambda b: (b[0] - p[0])**2 + (b[1] - p[1])**2, boundary)
    minDist2 = min(minDistList)
    return math.sqrt(float(minDist2))

d = []
for p in s1:
    d.append(nearestDistance(s2, p))
```

Should I change the structure of s1 and s2 (instead of points use 2d arrays for example)?

Comment: I do not think this can be anything better than **O(n^2)** *aka* try everything with everything else. Unless you do some clever math that will allow you to filter the `s2` for every item of `s1` somehow.

Comment: I was wondering if I could take advantage of the fact that s1 is actually a grid of coordinates, and there really is no need to try and compare elements of s2 with each element of s1

Comment: How large will s1 and s2 be in reality?

Comment: s1 is co-ordinates of an image meaning around 800 x 600, while s2 is a subset of the points in s1

Comment: @orak This changes the game quite significantly.. If `s2` is a subset of `s1` there will be some equalities in there (some elements of `s1` will be in `s2` too so min distance will be 0). Searching for those first will speed things up significantly. **O((n-k)^2)** with `k` the number of common elements.

Comment: oh, I might have used the word subset incorrectly, since I ignore some of the elements in s1 as well, otherwise the min distance would always be 0

Comment: Might be of interest: https://erikbern.com/2018/02/15/new-benchmarks-for-approximate-nearest-neighbors.html

Comment: this is also germane:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62400420/given-two-lists-of-2d-points-how-to-find-the-closest-point-in-the-2nd-list-for/62416370#62416370

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance

s1 = np.array([(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)])
s2 = np.array([(3,2), (1,9)])
print(distance.cdist(s1,s2).min(axis=1))
# array([3.60555128, 3.16227766, 2.82842712, 2.23606798])
```

Some more speed might be gained by directly outputting `0` for any point from `s1` that is also in `s2`.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried using [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

np.min(cdist(s1,s2))
```

returns

```
array([ 3.60555128,  3.16227766,  2.82842712,  2.23606798])
```

You might also get a performance boost by replacing `s1` and `s2` by `np.array`s, although `scipy` might be doing that internally, I'm not sure.

If this isn't optimised enough, I think you can do this in O(n<sub>s2</sub>*log(n<sub>s2</sub>) + n<sub>s1</sub>) by finding the [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram#Algorithms) of the points in `s2` and then looping through `s1` to see which region the point falls in which will match with the closest point in `s2`.

Comment: Damn, 7 seconds faster than me :D

Answer (score 3):

To calculate the N distances, there's not a better method than brute forcing all of the possibilities.  If you wanted something higher level, like perhaps the greatest or smallest distance, you could reduce the number of calculations based on some external knowledge, but the given your setup, the best you're going to get is O(n^2) performance.

EDIT: Given your comment, there are methods, that involve the general "divide and conquer" approach.  [Wikipedia has a good overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem), and I'll copy a perhaps relevant bit here:

> The problem can be solved in O(*n* log *n*) time using the recursive divide and conquer approach, e.g., as follows:
>
> 1. Sort points according to their x-coordinates.
> 2. Split the set of points into two equal-sized subsets by a vertical line *x* = *x<sub>mid</sub>*.
> 3. Solve the problem recursively in the left and right subsets. This yields the left-side and right-side minimum distances *d<sub>Lmin</sub>* and *d<sub>Rmin</sub>*, respectively.
> 4. Find the minimal distance *d<sub>LRmin</sub>* among the set of pairs of points in which one point lies on the left of the dividing vertical and the other point lies to the right.
> 5. The final answer is the minimum among *d<sub>Lmin</sub>*, *d<sub>Rmin</sub>*, and *d<sub>LRmin</sub>*.

Comment: Isn't the O(n log n) algorithm only for the closest pair of a set of points? How do you apply that to the problem of finding the closest point in a list (`s2`) to a fixed point (and the repeating this for all the points of `s1`)?

Answer (score 3):

Brute force is really the main way. You might be able to get squeeze some performance out using a KDTree since your data is low dimensional. [scipy.spatial.KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html)

```
kdtree = scipy.spatial.KDTree(s2)
neighbours = kdtree.query(s1)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Exact_methods discusses using a KD-tree for this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use the implementation of sklearn [pairwise_distances_argmin_min](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min) that given two point sets A and B returns the closest point *p*B in B and the distance from *pA* to *pB* for each point *pA* in A.

You then select the pair of points with the smallest distance of all in O(n*log n):

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances_argmin_min
import numpy as np

def get_closest_pair_of_points(point_list_1: List[Tuple[float]],
                           point_list_2: List[Tuple[float]]) -> Tuple[Tuple, Tuple, float]:
    """
    Determine the two points from two disjoint lists of points that are closest to 
    each other and the distance between them.

    Args:
        point_list_1: First list of points.
        point_list_2: Second list of points.

    Returns:
        Two points that make the closest distance and the distance between them.
    """
    indeces_of_closest_point_in_list_2, distances = pairwise_distances_argmin_min(point_list_1, point_list_2)

    # Get index of a point pair that makes the smallest distance.
    min_distance_pair_index = np.argmin(distances)

    # Get the two points that make this smallest distance.
    min_distance_pair_point_1 = point_list_1[min_distance_pair_index]
    min_distance_pair_point_2 = point_list_2[indeces_of_closest_point_in_list_2[min_distance_pair_index]]

    min_distance = distances[min_distance_pair_index]

    return min_distance_pair_point_1, min_distance_pair_point_2, min_distance
```

Of all implementations I have tested this is was fastest. It also does not have any limitations on the point distribution (such as two point sets being separable in space by a plane, etc.)