# Why is Scipy.spatial.distance.cdist fast if it uses a double for loop?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, scipy, scipy-spatial

I've been told that double for loops are slow in Python. However, while digging into the implementation of [Scipy.spatial.distance.cdist()](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/47bb6febaa10658c72962b9615d5d5aa2513fa3a/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L2606), I found that it's just a double for loop and not some clever numpy trick. And yet, many answers (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62416370) recommend using `cdist()`.

My question is: why is the function still so fast if it's just naively iterating over all elements in O(n^2)?

Comment: You are right is `O(n^2)` that being said **is fast because it uses the numpy/scipy implementations of the metrics** (this is where the bulk of the cost is). So is preferable to use that, in general, to a custom implementation.

Comment: The speed of numpy methods isn't because of some special trick that reduces the `O`.  It's because the iterations are done efficiently in compiled code.  A competent `C` programmer could write equally fast code.  It's not that numpy is so fast, but that python level loops are slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function with two for loops that you are pointing to, `_cdist_callable()`, is not used in most cases. When you read `cdist()` function you can see that `_cdist_callable()` is run for example when you provide your own metric function.

In typical scenario, when you provide metric in form of a string: `euclidean`, `chebyshev`, `cityblock`, etc., C-optimized functions are being used instead.
And "handles" to those C-optimized functions for those metrics are [listed here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/47bb6febaa10658c72962b9615d5d5aa2513fa3a/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L1776), in the same file.