# Find nearest neighbour to a set of points

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Let's consider n points: x_1, x_2,...,x_n that are multidimensional, and a distance metric d (let's assume that it calculates euclidean distance).

What I would love to have is an algorithm that search for a nearest neighbour (in terms of distance metric d) to each given point. I would like to have:

The closest neighbor to x_1 is x_7

The closest neighbor to x_2 is x_11

...
And so on for each point

I did some research on this topic and I found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) the statement of the problem, however I couldn't anywhere find a solution - preferably with mathematical explanation.

Do you have anything to recommend or give me any hints about solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you need the best algorithm or just a working solution? I believe the brute force will have time complexity of `O(dn^2)`. Note that euclidean distance is not advised when d>10

Comment: If `d` is small, the best solution is to stick it into a K-D tree. If `d` is large, the best solution is brute force. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality for why the dimension matters so much.

Comment: This might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62400420/given-two-lists-of-2d-points-how-to-find-the-closest-point-in-the-2nd-list-for/62416370#62416370

Comment: In high-dimensional spaces, the curse of dimensionality causes the algorithm to need to visit many more branches than in lower-dimensional spaces. In particular, when the number of points is only slightly higher than the number of dimensions, the algorithm is only slightly better than a linear search of all of the points. As a general rule, if the dimensionality is k, the number of points in the data, n, should be much larger than 2^k. - wikipedia