# 2D point matching with different sized arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, kdtree

I have 2 arrays, A and B with sizes (2, 25919) and (2, 64788) respectively. I have been attempting to compare the row and column values of array B against the values in point A to see which ones fall within a specified radius of point A.

I have tried the sectioning and KDTree examples in [Given two lists of 2d points, how to find the closest point in the 2nd list for every point in the 1st list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62400420/given-two-lists-of-2d-points-how-to-find-the-closest-point-in-the-2nd-list-for) , which is a close question to my own. However, since my own arrays are 2 different sizes, I get errors.

My own code right now looks like this:

```
A = [decamra, decamdec]
B = [ra, dec]

tree = KDTree(A)
results = tree.query_ball_point(B, r=r)
result = sum(len(list) for lis in results)
```

which returns the error "x must consist of vectors of length 25919 but has shape (2, 64788)".

Again, I want the code to find all the points in B that fall within the radius of a point of A and I have tried so many other different methods but the array size seems to be the biggest issue I am having here. Is there a way to modify this code so the array sizes don't have to match?

Answer (score 0):

Take an outer subtraction using broadcasting to calculate every possible pair distance and then compare. Since you need all of A, you can section B and just concatenate the results.

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 100, (2, 25919))
B = np.random.randint(0, 100, (2, 10000))  # B too large

radius = 5

dist = A[:, :, None] - B[:, None]
dist = np.square(dist).sum(axis=0)
dist = np.sqrt(dist)

B_close = B[:, np.any(dist <= radius, axis=0)]
```