# Finding minimum distance between points using two iterative lists and 'in range (0,len a_list))

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, coordinates

So i have a question that needs solving and the answer has to be fixed within a set of parameters. I've searched Stack for hours on this but can't find anything that helps. I'm new to Python and this is part of a quiz but without enough knowledge on iteration through lists I'm lost!

I know the solution to this having done the brute force method manually and looking at the scatter graph that comes out but I can't get the code to generate what I expect.

**Code as follows**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = [1, 7, 2, 10, 3, 4, 8, 4] 
ys = [1, 2, 4, 9, 16, 0, 12, 8]

plt.scatter(xs, ys)

import math

"""Compute the minimun distance between points given as lists for 
x, y coordinates. Return the values for the closest pair of points.""" 

def min_distance(xs, ys):
    """assume inputs xs, ys are lists of same length representing
    x,y point ordinates where points are distinct
    start with a high number as lowest"""
    min_dist = 99999
    min_index1 = 0
    min_index2 = 0
    
    # iterate x,y ordinates to find minimum distance
    """YOUR CODE GOES HERE - BEGIN"""
    for i in range (0, len(xs)):
        for j in range (0, len(ys)):
            if i > min_index1 and j > min_index2:
                min_dist = math.sqrt((xs[i] - xs[j])**2 + (ys[i] - ys[j])**2)
    """YOUR CODE GOES HERE - END"""

    return(min_index1, min_index2, min_dist)

index1, index2, d = min_distance(xs, ys)
print("Closest ordinates {},{} with distance: {}".format(index1,index2,d))
```

***The only code I'm supposed to change is the bit in the grey box that I have attempted to code myself (after it states ENTER YOUR CODE HERE)***

Comment: Potential duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887912/find-minimum-distance-between-points-of-two-lists-in-python/48888321

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. First of all, inside the nested loop you're doing

```
xs[i] - xs[i]
```

which always returns zero.

And maybe I misunderstood the question, but if all of your points are generated by p_i = (xs[i],ys[i]), then for every p_i check the distance between the others points p_j (j > i), and store the minimum and the index of these points on the process.

Comment: Yes thats the point, I know it's returning 0 but I don't know how to amend it so it loops through the list, I guess the Min_index would have to be used and increased by one each time

Answer (score 0):

So, the function you are looking for is zip: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

With it you can iterate over your coordinates like:

```
for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
    calculate distance here
    list_of_distances.append((x, y, distance))
```

You also want to store everything, so you can use min() or sorted() to find the lowest.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

Comment: Thanks Lily, yes agreed zip is a very clever solution to this and one I did use but my issue is remaining with the realms of the parameters set.
I am still none the wiser why someone wants me to follow such a long method to get to an answer but thats what Im stuck with

Answer (score 0):

The question could indeed be edited inline with the comments on others answers. There might be a better solution for this, but here a solution that will iterate through every point combination. It creates a distance matrix and then looks for the positions where the minimum was found. Note that performance will be of concern for very large arrays.

```
xs = [1, 7, 2, 10, 3, 4, 8, 4]
ys = [1, 2, 4, 9, 16, 0, 12, 8]

from typing import List, Tuple
import numpy as np

x  = np.array(xs)
y  = np.array(ys)

def get_idx_min_dist(x: np.array, y: np.array) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    DIST_MAT = np.full((len(x),len(y)), np.inf)
    
    xy = [(i, j) for i, j in zip(x, y)]
    
    for i, point1 in enumerate(xy):
        for j, point2 in enumerate(xy):
            if i != j:
                DIST_MAT[i, j] = (point1[0] - point2[0])**2 + (point1[1] - point2[1])**2
    
    min_pos  = DIST_MAT.argmin()
    first_point = min_pos // len(x)
    second_point = min_pos % len(x)
    
    return first_point, second_point

first, second = get_idx_min_dist(x, y)
print(first, second)
```

The output is:
`0 2`

**EDIT**
You might want to use `combinations` from `itertools` and create all different point pair combinations instead of creating a big dist matrix and consequent expensive search for min values.

Comment: Thats works amazingly well, and I actually got a solution turning the two data sets into a matrix and solving from there however the issue I have is that the question set states I have to follow the code used and I'm only allowed to enter code from the point ENTER YOUR CODE HERE, the start and end must remain the same.

It's the longest way I can see of solving this but I think its a test of coding rather than actually finding a sensible solution!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help all, after a lot of trial by error I got the answer

```
for i in range (len(xs)-1):
        for j in range (i+1,len(ys)):
            min_distance = math.sqrt((xs[i] - xs[j])*2 + (ys[i] - ys[j])*2)
            if min_distance < min_dist:
                    min_dist = min_distance
                    min_index1 = xs[i]
                    min_index2 = ys[j]
```

Comment: I am confused: why do you assign the values as indices, one from `xs` and another from `ys`? Otherwise the solution is ok. In the end it implements the idea of combinations as referred in my answer.

Comment: Because that was the question and I had to answer within the parameters of what I was given as a test. Other than that your answer was actually better

Comment: No, that was not what you asked in the original question. You wanted the indices and in your solution you are returning the values at the indices. Yes the solution is simpler.

Comment: Apologies,thats what I thought I asked or at least I was supposed to ask.