# Pandas merge two dataframes on nearest distance between coordinates

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets that I need to join together based on the nearest distance between coordinates (latitude and longitude)

`df1` contains information about air pollution measurements and looks like this:

| station_air | latitude | longitude | measurement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 53.23 | 4.81 | 60 |
| 2 | 51.93 | 5.82 | 140 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

`df2` contains data collected by weather stations and looks like this:

| station_air | latitude | longitude | measurement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 310 | 52.46 | 4.51 | 12.3 |
| 290 | 51.48 | 5.82 | 15.6 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

There are other columns such as time of measurement, date, month etc etc but are not relevant for this question. All stations in both `df1` and `df2` are unique, so we can't merge on their ID.

Ideally, I want the following table:

| station_air | latitude | longitude | measurement | temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| .. | ... | ... | ... | ... |

It comes down to this: for each row (`station_air`) in `df1`, find in `df2` the weather station with the closest distance to that `station_air`, and add `temp`.

I googled around and found this:
[Haversine Formula in Python (Bearing and Distance between two GPS points)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points)

But this takes too long since my `df1` is around 1,5mil rows

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: How long is df2? and are you iterating over df2 entirely or a filtered df2? Also, this sounds like an opportunity to use multiprocessing or threading. or https://dask.org/

Comment: df2 is around 39k rows. Ideally I want to iterate over the entire data. I'll look into multiprocessing, thank you

Comment: Further reading. Also if you want to post a bit more if your data for both data frames you may get some other advice or help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887912/find-minimum-distance-between-points-of-two-lists-in-python