# How can I efficiently find the minimum distance values for points in two very large 3D coordinate arrays?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, optimization, scipy

Let's pretend we have two arrays of 3D coordinate points.

A = (1000000, 3) of type float,
B = (100000, 3) of type float

For each coordinate in A, I would like to find the minimum euclidean distance to any coordinate in B. This means that it should calculate the euclidean distance between A[0], for instance, with all of B, and then take the smallest value.

I wrote up code to do this using loops. It works, but due to the size of my arrays it takes more than an hour to complete. The pseudocode looks something like this:

```
minDistances = np.zeros(A.shape)
for i in range(len(A)):
  queriedPoint = A[i]
  distances = B - queriedPoint
  euclideanDistances = np.linalg.norm(distances, axis=1)
  minDistance = np.min(euclideanDistances)
  minDistances[i] = minDistance
```

Ideally, I'd like to vectorize this, but in doing so it seems to crash my program from RAM usage. Any ideas or tips for how to do this more efficiently? I was wondering if maybe I could reduce the problem to something easier somehow, or else rethink how to approach it alltogether. Thanks!

Comment: `minDistances` is supposed to be an 1D (1000000,) array? Or a 2D (1000000,3) array? Its creation says one thing, its usage another

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find minimum distance between points of two lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887912/find-minimum-distance-between-points-of-two-lists-in-python)

Comment: @Woodford Yes and no. Most of those methods do a full m*n distance calculation. It would produce data in an intermediate format that could be processed to get what OP wants, but not may be the most efficient.

Comment: Critically, _take the smallest value_. Most of the methods in the answers of that question are brute-force (though KD-tree is mentioned)

Comment: If your data have characteristics that an algorithm could take advantage of, then show them here; otherwise, yes, this is a dupe. Edit the question to depict a density plot of your data, and specify whether either of the data set is to be longer-lived (i.e. if it can benefit from pre-processing).

Comment: @Reinderien You'll be hard pressed to prove any method is the "most efficient". In any case, the two posts ask the same question and, indeed, the example code in both questions produce the same result. This question is a duplicate.

Comment: If the goal is to find which point is closest and not actually calculate all the distances, then I am with @Reinderien. Using a kd-tree would be faster than the accepted, brute-forced, answer in the proposed duplicate question. Though, some tests would need to be done to figure out when one method is more efficient than the other, considering the overhead of building the kd-tree.

Comment: This is germane as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62400420/given-two-lists-of-2d-points-how-to-find-the-closest-point-in-the-2nd-list-for/62416370#62416370

Comment: Given two points (Xa, Ya) and (Xb, Yb) then the distance between them cannot be less than abs(Xa - Xb). Doing a simple subtraction is faster than calculating the full Euclidian distance, so you can save some time by quickly eliminating distant points.

Comment: Do one of the solutions solve your problem or is your problem still unanswered? If it's solved, you can accept one of the answers. Otherwise, please clarify what remains to be the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way to do this is probably using [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html). The [proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887912/find-minimum-distance-between-points-of-two-lists-in-python) recommends using [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html), but your arrays are too large that it would consume too much memory.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
A = rng.uniform(low=-100, high=100, size=(1_000_000, 3))
B = rng.uniform(low=-100, high=100, size=(100_000, 3))

tree = KDTree(B)
distances = tree.query(A)[0]
```

I don't know the actual range of values in `A` and `B`, so I just used `(-100, 100)`. This takes about 2.2 seconds to run.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force will require NxN distance calculations.

A simpler method is to use "bucketing", i.e. use some special boxes.

Building boxes requires about 4N calculations. For example, first pass determine the max & min X,Y,Z, coords for each array. Then you split the "space" into say 4x4x4=64 boxes for array_1 and other 64 for array_2.

By simple vertices comparisons you can get the two boxes (one for each array) that are closer. Yes, this is brute force, but with small data.

Note: If boxes intersect or there are more than one close pair, then you need a list of candidates, more boxes, but still not the initial big data.

Then run new pass on the arrays. Get only those points that lay in the list of boxes.

Finally you can run a brute-force with that chosen points.

For a pesimal case, where most of boxes of array_1 intersect (or are at same distance) with some boxes of array_2, then just split each box into eight smaller boxes and check again. The worst case may be (but rare) worst that brute force with the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so the best way is to divide the problem into subproblems, divide and conquer algorithm ;) so given the pseudocode above, we can try to attempt it by utilizing dict & list comprehension

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(1000000,3)
B = np.random.rand(1000000,3)

minDistance = {i: np.linalg.norm(B-A[i],axis=1).min() for i in range(len(A))}
minDistance = [minDistance[i] for i in range(len(A))]

print(minDistance)
```

by using dict & list comprehension, they help to optimize both time and complexity. hope that helps

Alternatively, you can try the loop-based approach

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

A = np.random.rand(1000000,3)
B = np.random.rand(1000000,3)

minDist = np.zeros(len(A))

for i, coord in enumerate(A):
    distances = cdist(np.expand_dims(coord,axis=0),B)
    minDist[i] = np.min(distances)
print(minDist)
```

Comment: Although they might produce the correct results, these are both very unoptimized solutions and are not well suited for this application. They each take tens of minutes to run.

Answer (score 0):

If the two arrays are filled with completely random numbers, then perhaps there’s little to be done. If each array corresponds to for example a vehicle track, then you should look at the Hausdorff distance and the Fréchet metric.